# Why do classes need arguments (argument) if I can simply add as many self.agrument after the __init__ as I need?

Tags: python, class, init

Like in the example below, my class has only the default self included, everything else is added under the init method.

```
class Settings():
def __init__(self):
'''screen settings'''
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
```

Comment: That's fine if you want all instances to have the exact same values for those attributes when created - but usually you want to be able to create instances with different attributes.

Comment: you could ask the same question to functions or pretty much the whole program itself then you might find the answer you are looking for

Comment: I would read up on object oriented design and static classes, functions, and members. You might be looking to create a static class as opposed to an instantiated class (an object is an instance of this kind of class). A static class allows you to group together similarly used code, without creating an object, thus without relating it to the same chunk of data. Typically you pass in different data to different objects, which would be why you construct your object with parameters. In a static class, you might have constant data that you reference in static methods, like you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't arguments to your class because they are class variables, that can be accessed by other functions in that class but aren't able to be used outside that class, if you wanted to make a variable from an argument to be used it would be

```
def __init__(self, fname, lname):
    self.firstname = fname
    self.lastname = lname
```

---

They can be called the same thing but can also can be called separate things.
If you want to access them from another function in that class this is how you do it

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def print_name(self):
    print(self.name)
```

The reason you have `self.` is so it is easier to manage the variables and keep track, the `self` argument is passed to the second function so it is able to use variables declared as class variables.

Comment: So the parameters have fixed values and I cannot change them outside the class itself if I don't declare them inside the __init__ method? e.g. self.screen_width = 1200 can only be 1200 unless I go back to the class and change it, but if i write __init__(self, screen_width) I can change it outside the class? ...is that the point?

Comment: Yes, you can also change the variable value in another function in the same class as it is declared in, if you have the variable as an argument when you call the class you can determine the variables value upon class declaration like this `Name("bob").print_name()` from my answer this would print out `bob`